# Fire event on create and another record

Tags: php, laravel, events, eloquent

I try to create company and user. When company was created should fire event created. I register observer and everything is ok. But user need to has password and email (this data are send from form) but company table doesn't have this fields. Currently I declare in `Company` model two fields `public $tmpEmail` and `public $tmpPassword` while I assign attributes I fill this properties. Afterwards I read this properties in my observer class, but for me is not good enough approach. How I can do it better?

Simplified example:

```
class Company extends Model
{
    $fillable = ['company_name', 'phone_number'];
}

class CompanyObserver
{
    public function created(Company $company)
    {
        print_r($company->company_name);
        print_r($company->tmpPassword);
        print_r($company->tmpEmail);
        $user = new User(['name' => $company->company_name', 'email' => $company->tmpEmail, 'password' => $this->tmpPassword);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you create the company? from an response function?

Comment: Currently in test (TDD :)), buy finally company will be created in controller.

Comment: Please consider my answer like an idea "well" formatted. Before downvoting writ in the comments. In your unit test you should test just the insert inside the model. In your controller you test company and user together

Answer (score 0):

*Just an idea formatted*

In my opinion you are creating too many porposes in a model. `Company` should know just itself.

If you have a scenario like an action from a form:

```
public function actionFromForm(Request $request) {
   $company = //Save your model
   $user = new User(['name' => $company->company_name, 'email' => $request->input('tmpEmail'), 'password' => $request->input('tmpPassword'));
}
```

Comment: This is good when if I use this only in controlles, but I need something automatically, because I won't create `User` object each place when I want to create company. `Company` know only about itself, this is role of observer pattern to looking on company and after some action (in my case create) add user. You have right now `Company` has unnecessary info (about user) but this my question, how figure it out, using observer patter.